# lowest config required for windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

Looking for some feedback on installing Windows7 on a not-so-latest configuration laptop.

I have a Intel Celeron 1.5Ghtz (32 bit) with 2GB RAM, Shared graphics , 40GB hdd.

currently i have windows-xp ( sp3 ) installed on this machine and is working fine. I am looking for a performance improvement by using windows7 which is a lighter OS.

Just want to know if its worth installing it on this configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have got it working on similar specifications - a 1.5Ghz single core, 64 bit celeron, 1GB of memory and a 80GB hard drive.

It used about 20GB on the hard drive so your 40GB should be fine... I had half the amount of memory and it was fine, my CPU was probably slightly faster, I am guessing mine is newer as it is x64.

However, it didn't win any speed records. If you are happy with XP, keep with it. Windows 7 might make your pc feel fresher and newer, and there shouldn't be any problems, but if you want it to run as fast as a new pc, you will have to disable a lot of services and features (For example, your graphics probably do not support aero), by the time you have done that, there is little reason for upgrading.

If you have a spare external hard drive, it may be worth creating an image of your machine, then installing and seeing if you like 7. If you do - stick with it, if not, go back to the image.

Comment: +1... 
x64 Vs x32 cpu consumption might be the same for the processes running ?

my motivation for Win7 is to be able to run dev tools in parallel. right now if i run VS Studio 2008 and something else in parallel the cpu is pretty much at the max for any other parallel tasks.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not directly answering your question, but you could download and install the [Windows 7 Upgrade Advisor](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=1B544E90-7659-4BD9-9E51-2497C146AF15&displaylang=en) which will produce a report on your current hardware.

It tells you whether it will work at all and whether it will work with limitations (e.g. No Aero Windows)

Answer (score 0):

What will you be doing on it? I run Win7 (32-bit) on an Intel Atom 1.33Ghz with 2GB RAM and 60GB HDD, and it's fine for browsing the net, and using Office.

Answer (score 0):

It would be worth mentioning in the concluding remarks by Wil above, to download [DriveImageXML](http://www.runtime.org/driveimage-xml.htm) which does a fine job in imaging the drive, you can then put the the image on to a spare hard-disk. Keep a copy of that DriveImageXML on the spare hard-disk also as you will be needing to use it to restore the image from if so required.

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.